# Setting a global text colour and retaining the disabled button colour

Tags: android, button, text, colors, styles

I cannot seem to get what I want no matter how much reading I do on this subject - yet what I want is quite simple.

I am applying a global style to my app based on AppCompat NoActionBar. This gives white text and I want to change it to a dark colour. Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff4400</item>
</style>


<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

This is fine. The text colour is changed to a dark colour everywhere (set to red here so I can see what's happening). Unfortunately this also overrides all of the text colouring for buttons. Disabled buttons show the dark colour and there is no way to distinguish them from enabled buttons. I've tried applying styles to buttons but the textColor always overrides the disabled colour.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed. I don't want to apply a selector on every button nor colour all the buttons individually by setting a style on each one. I want an overall global colour change - which Android seems to have made exceptionally difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to get it to work. I had to use a selector. I provide my solution below.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorTertiary</item>
</style>


<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```